# Find slope in degrees between two vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Slope]

Hi,
I found a large number of references but without being able to adapt them to my needs.
As per attached figures I have my character in a given position. Below the character's feet is a new plane (). With the mouse wheel I move the character up along the Y axis and the plane moves with it. Then I drag the character to any position and I join the three vector3s with Gizmos lines. Now I need to know the slope in degrees between the starting point (the red point) and the new position of the character. I tried to use Vector3.Angle or Atan2 and many examples found around but all return different values when you rotate the character despite the slope is always the same. For example `charAngle = Vector3.Angle (initialCharPos - character.transform.position, Vector3.left)` returns the correct value only in that certain direction and I can get the 4 points left, right, forward, back. But for directions other than these? I was wondering if for each of the 360 points it is necessary to make checks based on the direction or if there is a faster way to get this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Vector3.Angle`, you just need to take it between the down direction & the direction from the new feet position to the start feet position, and subtract the result from 90:

```
Vector3 newFeetPosition;
Vector3 startFeetPosition;

// direction of "down", could be different in a zero g situation for instance
Vector3 downDirection = Vector3.down:

float slopeDegrees = 90f - Vector3.Angle(newFeetPosition - startFeetPosition, downDirection);
```

---

If you need the rise/run for other reasons, you can get them in the process of calculating the angle yourself using vector math:

```
Vector3 newFeetPosition;
Vector3 startFeetPosition;

// direction of "up", could be different in a zero g situation for instance
Vector3 upDirection = Vector3.up:

Vector3 feetDiff = newFeetPosition - startFeetPosition:

float riseMagnitude = Vector3.Dot(feetDiff, upDirection);

Vector3 riseVector = riseMagnitude * upDirection;

float runMagnitude = (feetDiff - riseVector).magnitude;

float slopeDegrees = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan2(riseMagnitude, runMagnitude);
```